# Determinant of a metric in the three dimensional positive?

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

In the three dimensional Euclidean space, given any basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$. Then, does the determinant of the metric $g_{ij}=e_i \cdot e_j$ always have positive value? It was easy to show in the 2 dimension, but I cannot find a way to prove it in the three dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ denote the matrix whose columns are $e_1,e_2,e_3$.  We then note that $G = A^TA$.  It follows that 
$$
\det(G) = \det(A^T) \det(A) = \det(A)^2
$$
so yes: if $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis, then $\det(G)$ is positive.